# What advantage does Kawasaki C-2 have with a twin-engine configuration as compared to its competitors like An-70 or A-400?

Tags: jet-engine, military, cargo, transport-category, japan

While reading about various military transports, I came across the specs of **Kawasaki C-2** and a few questions popped up. So please bear with me here if I list them all together as points, I hope someone here will help me understand more by answering this.

1) What advantage does the C-2's get with a twin-engine setup when compared to the 4 engine set up in most of its competitors **(A-400, An 70/188)** which have similar MTOW's?

2) The next question is related to C-2's MTOW & payload - with a 145tn MTOW the An 70/188 has a max payload of 47tn but with a 141tn MTOW the max payload of C-2 is a full 10tn less at 37tn. Also, considering that the dimensions are very close to each other what is the reason for such a huge difference?

3) Next is again payload & thrust related - the max thrust generated by C-2's twin engines is at **532 kN (266 x 2)** its close to the **468-568 kN (117 or 142 x 4)** of the IL76MD-90A and higher than the **468-500 kN (117 or 125 x 4)** listed for the Y-20, but both these platforms list a much higher payload capability (~50-66 tn max.) while I understand that the MTOW of the other two are much higher which gives them much higher fuel load and range, shouldn't the similar thrust mean it can carry similar payloads even if it is for a shorter range? Can someone explain to me why such a huge divergence?

4) Lastly is a bit general, I couldn't find the max fuel capacity of the C-2 from any open sources or articles, so, if someone could answer that and share any interesting things they know about C-2 that would be great.

Comment: I'll leave answer to people who know more but I am pretty sure most differences are due to the customer specifying much higher cruise speed than competing designs have. Certainly this explains your engine questions. The customer also specified a minimum payload which C-2 exceeds by wide margin. Higher payload simply was not needed. Possibility of exporting to other customers with other needs only materialized **after** C-2 was designed.

Comment: Far too many questions for the SE format.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Thanks..I was also hoping to hear from someone with some knowledge in this area, hence the post here...

Comment: @FreeMan I was trying to just club related questions under one post in order to prevent from being flagged as duplicates, also considering that all are related to one Aircraft. So do you suggest that I should post these as separate questions?